# Sublime text does not preserve unsaved files on quit even with hot_exit setting

Tags: sublime-text-3

Sublime Text Version 3.2.2, Build 3211

My user preferences file:

```
{
    "hot_exit": true,
    "remember_open_files": true
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1- open sublime text app

2- write text in unsaved file

3- Quit Sublime text (cmd+Q)

4- open sublime text

5- content disappears and sublime text opens a new blank file instead

Am I missing any other settings?

Comment: [auto-save - Packages - Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/auto-save)?

Comment: I need to auto-save unsaved buffers that are not in files, I think this package only auto-saves unsaved files